# A process called "accountsd" is making my iMac Late-2013 unusable. Any ideas? (MacOS Catalina 10.15.7)

Tags: imac

So, it has been a few days since my computer started having problems to open the google chrome browser. I checked the activity monitor and there is a process called "accountsd" which is using around 200% of the CPU power. Any suggestions? Thanks :D[image: Activity Monitor]

[image: macos build]

Comment: And I'm guessing it started after a software update, right? ;) You're not alone! https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3970/how-should-we-be-closing-or-not-closing-accountsd-using-400-cpu-type-questions

Comment: I’ll point this to some great answers for the general question. If you edit this to show your precise macos build and version we can see about reopening this or linking to the question that covers your version steps to fix this.

Comment: @bmike I added a picture with that info ;)